# How can I get the first 4 row values into one row in seperate columns for each visit_id record?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a `patient_visit_codes` table with the fields: `pat_id, visit_id, visit_date, visit_code, create_timestamp`. Each patient can have infinite # of visit codes for each visit date. Each `visit_code` is listed in a separate row. I want to get just the first 4 `visit_code` created into one row in seperate columns.

So if my table has the data below:

```
;WITH patient_visit_codes AS (
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
(1, 'B58B3850-43BB-434D-B1EA-B968A01332EA', '2015-12-22', '3018F', '2015-12-22 07:24:07.403'),
(1, 'B58B3850-43BB-434D-B1EA-B968A01332EA', '2015-12-22', '1101F', '2015-12-22 07:28:09.440'),
(56, '482A73F8-EA3F-4CD6-B1AD-BD2388EC5912', '2016-01-05', 'I50', '2016-01-05 11:05:34.830'),
(56, '482A73F8-EA3F-4CD6-B1AD-BD2388EC5912', '2016-01-05', 'R50.90', '2016-01-05 11:35:14.560'),
(56, '482A73F8-EA3F-4CD6-B1AD-BD2388EC5912', '2016-01-05', 'Z02.89', '2016-01-05 11:40:24.740')
) as t (pat_id, visit_id, visit_date, visit_code, create_timestamp))
```

I'm looking to get results like below:

```
pat_id  | visit_id                              | visit_code1   | visit_code2   | visit_code3   | visit_code4 
1       | B58B3850-43BB-434D-B1EA-B968A01332EA  | 3018F         | 1101F         | Null          | Null 
56      | 482A73F8-EA3F-4CD6-B1AD-BD2388EC5912  | I50           | R50.90        | Z02.89        | Null
```

Comment: Which Database MSSQL or MySQL

Comment: Please specify which SQL you are asking, the answer may involve using pivot function in which syntax may be different.

Comment: My apologies, I am using Sql Server 2012

Comment: Sql server management studio version 11.0.5058.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using MS SQL 2012 I came up with the below that should get you the desired output.  It involves creating a subquery/CTE to RANK the visits by Date and then 4 self-joins to throw them all onto a single row entry:

```
WITH cte
AS
    (SELECT pat_ID, visit_ID, visit_date, visit_code, create_timestamp,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY pat_ID ORDER BY visit_date, create_timestamp) AS RankNo
    FROM #t)

SELECT a.pat_id, a.visit_id, a.visit_code AS visit_code1, b.visit_code AS visit_code2, 
    c.visit_code AS visit_code3, d.visit_code AS visit_code4
FROM cte AS a
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM cte AS b WHERE b.RankNo = 2) AS b
ON a.pat_ID = b.pat_ID
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM cte AS c WHERE c.RankNo = 3) AS c
ON a.pat_id = c.pat_ID
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM cte AS d WHERE d.RankNo = 4) AS d
ON a.pat_ID = d.pat_ID
WHERE
    a.RankNo = 1
```

For the RANK() function I did ORDER BY for both the visit_date and create_timestamp to elminate ties...if there's a chance a visit_date will be at the exact time it's created you may want to add a third ORDER BY

This will provide the desired output but I'd also suggest Googling SQL dynamic pivot to see alternative solutions

Comment: Late response but the examples above worked beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML for this:

```
DECLARE @xml xml

;WITH patient_visit_codes AS (
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
(1, 'B58B3850-43BB-434D-B1EA-B968A01332EA', '2015-12-22', '3018F', '2015-12-22 07:24:07.403'),
(1, 'B58B3850-43BB-434D-B1EA-B968A01332EA', '2015-12-22', '1101F', '2015-12-22 07:28:09.440'),
(56, '482A73F8-EA3F-4CD6-B1AD-BD2388EC5912', '2016-01-05', 'I50', '2016-01-05 11:05:34.830'),
(56, '482A73F8-EA3F-4CD6-B1AD-BD2388EC5912', '2016-01-05', 'R50.90', '2016-01-05 11:35:14.560'),
(56, '482A73F8-EA3F-4CD6-B1AD-BD2388EC5912', '2016-01-05', 'Z02.89', '2016-01-05 11:40:24.740')
) as t (pat_id, visit_id, visit_date, visit_code, create_timestamp))

, xml_t AS (
SELECT DISTINCT 1 as Tag,
        0 as Parent,
        pat_id as [pat!1!id], 
        visit_id  as [pat!1!visit_id],
        NULL as [visit!2!visit_code]
FROM patient_visit_codes 
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 2 as Tag,
        1 as Parent,
        pat_id as [pat!1!id], 
        visit_id as [pat!1!visit_id],
        visit_code as [visit!2!visit_code]
FROM patient_visit_codes)

SELECT @xml = (
SELECT *
FROM xml_t
ORDER BY [pat!1!id], [pat!1!visit_id],[visit!2!visit_code]      
FOR XML EXPLICIT) 

--we get xml like that:
--<pat id="1" visit_id="B58B3850-43BB-434D-B1EA-B968A01332EA">
--  <visit visit_code="1101F" />
--  <visit visit_code="3018F" />
--</pat>
--<pat id="56" visit_id="482A73F8-EA3F-4CD6-B1AD-BD2388EC5912">
--  <visit visit_code="I50" />
--  <visit visit_code="R50.90" />
--  <visit visit_code="Z02.89" />
--</pat>

SELECT  Component.value('@id','int') as pat_id,
        Component.value('@visit_id','nvarchar(32)') as visit_id,
        Component.value('(visit/@visit_code)[1]','nvarchar(10)') as visit_code1,
        Component.value('(visit/@visit_code)[2]','nvarchar(10)') as visit_code2,
        Component.value('(visit/@visit_code)[3]','nvarchar(10)') as visit_code3,
        Component.value('(visit/@visit_code)[4]','nvarchar(10)') as visit_code4
FROM @xml.nodes('/pat') as X(Component)
```

and result is:

```
pat_id      visit_id                         visit_code1 visit_code2 visit_code3 visit_code4
----------- -------------------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           B58B3850-43BB-434D-B1EA-B968A013 1101F       3018F       NULL        NULL
56          482A73F8-EA3F-4CD6-B1AD-BD2388EC I50         R50.90      Z02.89      NULL

(2 row(s) affected)
```